# nodemon not watching workspace dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, yarn-workspaces

I use `nodemon` to watch file changes in a TypeScript **Node.JS** codebase. When a change is detected, **esbuild** and **esbuild-register** are used to transpile the code to CommonJS files and the application restarts.

The application is part of a monorepo with **yarn workspaces**. I use some code from a shared package in my application.

How can i get `nodemon` to **automatically** watch dependencies from the **same workspace** for changes and trigger a restart?

My workaround is adding the **relative path** to all used linked dependencies in `watch` in `nodemon.json`, but that requires me to **manually** edit the configuration when I add a **local linked dependency**.

`nodemon.json`

```json
{
  "exec": "node -r esbuild-register",
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "watch": [
    "src",
    "../../packages/logger/src",
    "../../packages/helpers/src"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@app/logger": "*",
    "@app/helpers": "*"
  }
}
```